REPOST(NEED MORE EXPLANATIONS) : A 12th-grade physics question about inductors
I'm a 12th-grade student learning about inductors, and there's a question that’s been bothering me. I’m not an expert, which is why I’m asking here. If anyone knows the answer, please explain it as if you're explaining it to a 12th grader.
I'm studying inductors, and according to my school textbook, a change in current (dI/dt
) through an inductor produces a back emf. I know this can be explained using electromagnetism, so I tried to understand it in more depth, particularly the concept of length contraction (Lorentz contraction) and how it relates to creating a magnetic field.
Here's my thought process:
Suppose we have a DC circuit with a rheostat (or some device) that allows us to adjust the voltage. I set the voltage to 5 V, which results in a constant current (meaning no back emf is produced because dI/dt = 0. Now, if I change the voltage from 5 V to 10 V, three things happen:
1.At 5 V, the current is constant, so there’s no back emf.
2.At 10 V, the current is constant again, so still no back emf.
3.During the transition from 5 V to 10 V (I’ll call this the “transition time” or "TT"), there is a changing current, which should produce a back emf.
Teachers often say that this transition happens almost instantaneously, But it’s precisely during this TT that the back emf is created, which is why I think it’s important to understand what’s happening here.
My reasoning is as follows: If back emf is explained using magnetism, then during the transition time, electrons in the inductor windings should feel a repulsive force from adjacent windings. This repulsion must have a consistent direction. Otherwise, if it were random, the forces would cancel each other out, and we wouldn’t get a net back emf.
Also, closer windings should mean stronger inductance, at infinite pitch the inductor is a straight wire, which seems to support this idea.
The big question:
How can I connect all these concepts? I have some ideas, but I'm not fully convinced. My primary question is how a inductor works? My secondary question is more fundamental: What actually happens when I increase the voltage from 5 V to 10 V? Does the electric field change instantly throughout the conductor, moving at the speed of light? at this time what happens? And, what is magnetic potential energy in a real sense?

This question is similar to: A 12th-grade physics question about inductors. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

There were a lot of deleted comments; they are generally correct: Your new question is basically identical to the old one, showing no progress in learning. You need to at least learn to ask questions in a way that people would be interested in helping you. But on this topic, there is a lot of good resources online, even those with visualisations of their simulations and some even with direct measurements overlaid on the video feed. You should show some effort before coming back for help.

"At 5 V, the current is constant" That may be the heart of your misunderstanding. If you forced a constant voltage on an ideal inductor, then the current would not be constant.
It would steadily increase (at a constant rate) for as long as you maintained the voltage. Any real inductor acts, in the first order of approximation, like an ideal inductor in series with a resistor. If you force 5V across a real inductor,  then the current will approach a steady state, at which point, it will be as if the whole 5V was "dropped" by the resistance, and 0V is dropped by the ideal inductance.
